# onclick clone shipping address fields values to billing address fields values

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hi i have this javascript code

```
copyAddress : function(swapMode, container){
    var thisInstance = this;
    var addressMapping = this.addressFieldsMappingInModule;
    if(swapMode == "false"){
        for(var key in addressMapping) {
            var fromElement = container.find('[name="'+key+'"]');
            var toElement = container.find('[name="'+addressMapping[key]+'"]');
            toElement.val(fromElement.val());
        }
    } else if(swapMode){
        var swappedArray = thisInstance.swapObject(addressMapping);
        for(var key in swappedArray) {
            var fromElement = container.find('[name="'+key+'"]');
            var toElement = container.find('[name="'+swappedArray[key]+'"]');
            toElement.val(fromElement.val());   
        }
```

this code working fine if elements are input text fields
but not for select dropdown elements
I my form I have only input text and select fields and i want to modyfy this code to work with select fields too

I made a change to code like this

```
          if(!(fromElement).is("select")) {
            toElement.val(fromElement.val());
          }else{
            var $options = $(fromElement+" > option").clone();
            toElement.append($options); 
           }
```

but without success. 
Maybe anyone can help me please?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This will do your work.
I have added a check that if the element to copy is **Select** or not. In case of select element all the options of **From** element will be copied  and appended to **To** element.

Try it and let me in case of any issue.

```
   copyAddress : function(swapMode, container){
    var thisInstance = this;
    var addressMapping = this.addressFieldsMappingInModule;
    if(swapMode == "false"){
        for(var key in addressMapping) {
            var fromElement = container.find('[name="'+key+'"]');
            var toElement = container.find('[name="'+addressMapping[key]+'"]');
          if(fromElement[0].tagName == "Select")
            {
              toElement.find('option').remove();
              toElement.append(fromElement.find('option'));
            }
            toElement.val(fromElement.val());

        }
    } else if(swapMode){
        var swappedArray = thisInstance.swapObject(addressMapping);
        for(var key in swappedArray) {
            var fromElement = container.find('[name="'+key+'"]');
            var toElement = container.find('[name="'+swappedArray[key]+'"]');
          if(fromElement[0].tagName == "Select")
            {
              toElement.find('option').remove();
              toElement.append(fromElement.find('option'));
            }
            toElement.val(fromElement.val());   
        }
```

Comment: I just try it and did not worked. I forgot to say that form select use chosen.js

Comment: I added this too after  `code`toElement.append(fromElement.find('option')); toElement.trigger("chosen:updated");`code`

Comment: The problem is with select checker function if I ad this `      if(fromElement[0].tagName == "Select")
            {
           alert('select');
            }else{
   alert('textbox');
   }` I'm receiving alert textbox

Comment: i replaced the `tagName == "Select" to tagName == "SELECT"`and now i can get true when there is select but the option stay same

Answer (score 0):

The solution was `toElement.val(fromElement.val()).trigger("liszt:updated");` this work for all elements in form that use chosen.js